# gmock and forward declared classes

Tags: c++, forward-declaration, googlemock

Suppose i have this class and type Manager is forward declared in Base.h.

```
#include <Base.h>

class MockBase : public Base
{
public:
    MOCK_CONST_METHOD0( manager, const Manager&( ) );
    ...
};
```

I'm not going to use this method in my test, so i don't want to include definition of Manager class into the file with test.

But i think that while compiling gmock tries to prepare error message and deep in its guts it takes address of Manager variable and i have an error:

> error C2027: use of undefined type 'Manager'
>   \external\googlemock\gtest\include\gtest\gtest-printers.h 146 1

Can i somehow avoid inclusion of files with definitions of forward declared types for methods which i will not use?

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to define for UTs a generic `ostream` operator, which is activated only for forward-declared types. It has to be located in the global namespace. If included, it solves forward-declaration `gmock` problems for all types.
Users could still provide a custom `PrintTo` function, even for forward declared references, as `PrintTo` seems to be called first. It works for `gmock` 1.7 with `C++14` in GCC.

```
// A class to determine if definition of a type is available or is it forward declared only
template <class, class = void>
struct IsDefined : std::false_type
{};

template <class T>
struct IsDefined<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_object<T>::value 
                                     && not std::is_pointer<T>::value 
                                     && (sizeof(T) > 0)>>
    : std::true_type
{};

// It has to be in global namespace
template <
    typename T,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<
        not IsDefined<T>::value and 
        not std::is_pointer<T>::value and 
        std::is_object<T>::value>>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const T& ref)
{
    os << "Forward declared ref: " << static_cast<const void*>(&ref);
    // assert(false); // Could assert here as we do not want it to be executed
    return os;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've worked around this by defining a PrintTo function so gtest will not try to use its TypeWithoutFormatter function that causes the issue. This is unfortunate, and I'm not sure what a proper fix would be.

```
namespace Foo { void PrintTo(const Bar& x, ::std::ostream* os) { *os << "Bar " << &x; }}
```